# Wrap <ul> around every x number of <li> in category_archive entry loop

Tags: categories, jquery, javascript, html, category-archive

I'd like to use something similar to a `switch` or plugin like [Grouper](https://github.com/mattnicholson/EEgrouper) with `category_archive`, to wrap a `<ul>` around every 6 `<li>`, but I don't see anything that works. Is jQuery the best way to go or is the another solution I can use that doesn't need js/jQuery?

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    {exp:channel:category_archive channel="speakers" style="linear" backspace="7"}
        <li>
            {categories}
                <a href="#">{category_name}</a>
            {/categories} 
            {entry_titles}  
            <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
                <li><a href="{url_title_path='site/speaker'}">{title}</a></li>
            </ul>  
            {/entry_titles}     
        </li>   
    {/exp:channel:category_archive}     
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done, because `exp:channel:category_archive` doesn't use the Template Parser, so there aren't `count` or `total_results` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the conditionals available.
https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#mathematic-operators
Particularly the modulus operator.

Comment: Can't seem to get global variables like `{count}` to work in `category_archive` entry so not sure I can accomplish this way...unless I'm missing something. Thoughts?

Comment: A few lines or so of PHP should work. You'll set a counter just before the loop, then increment this counter for every lap of the loop, divide by six and check the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

i've done something similar to this before, though a bit different,  test something like this using the [Switchee](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) plugin.

```
{exp:channel:category_archive channel="speakers" style="linear" backspace="7"}
{switch="<ul class='list-unstyled'>|||||"}{!-- open a new <ul> at intervals of 6 entries --}
<li>
{categories}<a href="#">{category_name}</a>{/categories} 
{entry_titles}  
<ul class="list-unstyled"> 
<li><a href="{url_title_path='site/speaker'}">{title}</a></li>
</ul>  
{/entry_titles}     
</li>  
{if count != total_results}{switch="|||||</ul>"}{/if} {!-- close the </ul> at intervals of 6 as long as the current entry is not the last in the loop --}
{if count == total_results}</ul>{/if} {!-- always close the open </ul> after the last entry --}
{/exp:channel:category_archive}
```

Hope that helps?